# problems with VSCode flutter

Tags: android, debugging, visual-studio-code, flutter

after running flutter doctor in vscode

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
[X] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.2)
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.26.0)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

to fix Android license status unknown. i've tried to run on vscode terminal
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

but i get this msg

```
flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
```

now i've installed memuPlayer its an android emulator and its working fine with Intelij but seems like vscode just can't recognize it
I've tried to run `--enable-software-rendering` on terminal but i got this msg

```
'--enable-software-rendering' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

tried on terminal cmd and shell too any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Windows expert, but I think you have to put the path to the flutter binary in your PATH environment variable. Or you could call it with an absolute path (in the terminal, e.g. `C:\your\install\location\flutter\bin\flutter --android-licenses`).

Answer (score 1):

Add flutter to your environment path (System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> Use variables for user -> Path -> new -> add the path to flutter\bin dir) to remove the `flutter is not recognized as a internal or external command`